# How to print out all notes and calendar events on ColorNote?

Tags: calendar, notes, printing, colornote

I have the ColorNote app installed on Android. How do I go about printing the notes and the calendar events?

I am able to "view" all the data from the last backup. I am able to send an email to myself of a .doc file that was generated before I signed up for online sync. How do I print out the doc file? Microsoft Word is unable to read this .doc file.

Answer (score 0):

For one note, I send it to Gmail and then print the email.

Answer (score -1):

Highlight what you want on the ColorNote, copy it, open Word NotePad, and then paste and print the Word NotePad page.

Comment: How to load this file in PC? MS office can't do it as OP said. Also, you should mention that you are recommending the solution with PC in mind.

Comment: It is unclear if "Word NotePad" refers to "Microsoft Word", "NotePad on Windows", or a different app altogether, either on Android or Windows.